# WaitForSingleObject for a thread freezes when called from application globals

Tags: multithreading, winapi, waitforsingleobject

I create a thread as a part of some pool, that needs to be destroyed when the application (DLL actually) finishes. So I have a some "globals", meaning a structure instantiated globally statically and in the destructor it releases any created threads and waits for them using WaitForSingleObject. Unfortunately this freezes forever and checking in the debugger reveals that the threads are still there, just stuck somewhere in the system DLLs. When I call this before the globals are getting released, then all goes fine. I don't see any mentioning of this in the Win32 docs. Any ideas?

Comment: destructor called from dll entry point, inside loader lock critical section. thread, before exit, try enter to this critical section too, for send `DLL_THREAD_DETACH`. but can not, because it hold by thread which call `WaitForSingleObject`.

Comment: so your thread can not exit, until your `WaitForSingleObject` not exit, but `WaitForSingleObject` can exit until your thread not exit. relly you not need wait. when you create thread from dll - you need ad reference to dll. and thread must exit with `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` call. wait for thread exit not need - for what ?! you only need signal thread to exit, and this you already do, how i undertand

Comment: Yes, it's not needed in this case, so I solved it by removing the wait, but I don't understand why. It seems that the threads just cannot finish and they don't really need to wait for anything.

Comment: but i just explain you why is deadlock

Comment: [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices). Make sure you understand when your global constructors and destructors run.

Comment: *I solved it by removing the wait* in this case you thread in dll may crash - run unloaded dll code

Comment: [FreeLibraryAndExitThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-freelibraryandexitthread) addresses this specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is indeed to avoid waiting and actually releasing anything in the DllMain (including the globals) is bad, so one needs to release everything important before. That's sometimes a bit tricky, when it comes to DLLs, but well...

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.